# Here Maps - iOS - Is search history saved?

Tags: here-api

I am looking through the iOS Premium Developer's Guide. I see search but I don't see anywhere that indicates if a search history is maintained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search history is not maintained by the SDK. Please store the search terms in the application code.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your quick response, much appreciated. A follow up question related to offline search: In the Search & Discovery section of the guides it says "Note that offline search is supported when a data connection is unavailable, if the data required to perform the search has been previously downloaded." Do we need to store this data also or is this cache maintained by the Here SDK?

Comment: This section is referring to the offline map data which can be cached via the MapLoader APIs. 

We offer three modes in search. Offline, using offline data downloaded from panning the map and map loader. Online, using the HERE rest services. Hybrid where the engine automatically chooses online / offline depending on your data connection. So in the case you are describing, it is using offline search of the downloaded map data.